# Парсинг сайта через JSOUP в приложение с задержкой

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Есть сайт который грузит инфу через API или через js скрипт, не важно. Этому API нужно немного времени, чтобы загрузится на сайте. Получается что мой парсинг парсит сразу после загрузки страницы, но при этом этот API еще не прогрузился, и парситься пустой div. Как сделать задержу или проверку загрузки? Спасибо!

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            String url = "https://www.sate.com/";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("div#s-b");
            int size = data.size();
            Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
            Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
            Log.d("size", ""+size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                String data2 = data.select("tbody")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();

                Log.d("data2", "data2: " + data2);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: проверяйте наличие данных перед отображением страницы

Comment: Проблема не в задержке - `JSOUP` просто загружает исходник страницы и не выполняет никаких скриптов и других дополнительных действий, это не браузер.

Answer (score 1):

**С помощью JSoup это невозможно**. JSoup получает ответ исходного HTML кода, это не браузер который будет подгружать все ссылки в исходном HTML. Это означает, что он совершенно не знает что будет добавляется в DOM с помощью Javascript и прочих загрузок после начальной загрузки страницы.

Чтобы получить доступ к этому конечному html вам нужен будет WebClient или же встроенный браузер который в фоне загрузит страницу целиком, а только потом выдаст конечный html. Посмотрите как это можно сделать на примере WebView

Мой же совет разобраться в структуре сайта и парсить именно нужный вам api

Comment: а как сделать такой WebClient? есть примеры или инструкция? Как работать с WebView я знаю, но как от туда парсить?