# Передача с webview в jsoup

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Мне нужно сделать `webview` в котором будет загружаться сайт В ФОНЕ. После того как `webview` полностью загрузит сайт, парсить его с помощью `jsoup`. Как отслеживать ссылку с `webview` в `jsoup`?

Мой код на данный момент:

```
private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
        SBAdapterParse.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            String url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("div#col-content");
            int size = data.size();
            Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
            Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
            Log.d("size", ""+size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                String data2 = data.select("div#sb")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();

                Log.d("data2", "data2" + data2);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот зачем нужно сделать именно так, возможно кто-то предложит более простой вариант: [Парсинг сайта через JSOUP в приложение с задержкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1176456/399126)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892013 - примерно так вытаскиваете страницу, потом скармливаете парсеру. Но в скрытой `WebView` контент может прогрузиться не правильно. Как вам уже советовали, лучше разобраться в коде страницы, узнать как и откуда загружаются нужные вам данные и загрузить их напрямую.

Comment: @woesss это api через авторизацию работает. Там не все так просто... А как скормить эту страницу парсеру? В парсере указывается ссылка. Какую мне нужно там указать?

Comment: Ну в доки то надо заглядывать `Jsoup.parse(...)`: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html.

Comment: @woesss ну так это понятно, а дальше че писать?